# How can I append two select element to table rows with using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, html-table

I want to create a dynamic table according to assigned array as below image:

[image]

My code:

**HTML**

```
<table id="selectTable" class="m-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Products</th>
            <th>Range</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**JQUERY**

```
function drawTable(data) {

var dateTable = $('#selectTable');
selectEl  = $('<select>'),
    selectVal = [
        {val : 1, text: '1'},
        {val : 2, text: '2'},
        {val : 3, text: '3'},
        {val : 4, text: '4'},
        {val : 5, text: '5'}
    ];

$(selectVal).each(function() {
    selectEl
    .append($('<option>')
            .attr('value',this.val)
            .text(this.text));
});

dateTable.children('tbody').empty();

$.each(data,function(k,v){

    var row     = $('<tr />',{'class':'row-'+k});
    dateTable.append(row);
    row.append($('<td />').append(v));
    row.append($('<td />').append(selectEl + ' ' + selectEl ));

});
}

var a = ['Product-1','Product-2','Product-3','Product-4','Product-5'];


drawTable(a);
```

Table and selectbox will create dynamically and append to table each row. How can I do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/dsjLT/2/

Comment: It seems like `selectEl` is a jQuery collection, but you're concatenating as a string?

Comment: Why are you creating classes with variable name..? classes are meant to be common (*to be applied for multiple elements*)... If you're trying to distinguish a particular element, i suggest using an id instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I append two selectbox to each row with the following edit;

```
dateTable.append(row);
row.append($('<td />').append(v));
row.append($('<td />').append(selectEl));
row.children('td:nth-child(2)').append(selectEl.clone());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dsjLT/6/

Answer (score 3):

Not sure you can reuse the selectEl that way. I'd try to recreate it for each row. This works (though it needs cleanup):

```
function drawTable(data) {

  var dateTable = $('#selectTable');
  dateTable.children('tbody').empty();

  $.each(data,function(k,v){

    var selectEl  = $('<select>'),
      selectVal = [
        {val : 1, text: '1'},
        {val : 2, text: '2'},
        {val : 3, text: '3'},
        {val : 4, text: '4'},
        {val : 5, text: '5'}
      ];

      $(selectVal).each(function() {
        selectEl
       .append($('<option>')
               .attr('value',this.val)
               .text(this.text));
      });

      var row     = $('<tr />',{'class':'row-'+k});
      dateTable.append(row);
      row.append($('<td />').append(v));
      row.append($('<td />').append(selectEl));

   });
}

var a = ['Product-1','Product-2','Product-3','Product-4','Product-5'];

drawTable(a);
```

Comment: yes ok it's work but how can I append two selectbox to each row?

Comment: Two SELECTs? The same way, I guess. E.g. by breaking out the code to a function and calling it twice in each $.each loop. But then, this is just an example created to illustrate a problem, right?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is $('select') is the same instance and hence can only append to one row. You need to clone before append to the row.

Refer to http://jsfiddle.net/hutingung/dsjLT/3/

Snippet of the code

```
$.each(data,function(k,v){

    var row     = $('<tr />',{'class':'row-'+k});
    dateTable.append(row);
    row.append($('<td />').append(v));
    //you are refer to same instance of selectEL
    //row.append($('<td />').append(selectEl));
    //Use clone to append
    selectEl.clone().appendTo(row);

});
```